# Try echo service WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I try the echo service in WSO2 ESB. I send this message:

```
<body>
    <p:echoInt xmlns:p="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
        <!--0 to 1 occurrence-->
        <in>1</in>
    </p:echoInt>
</body>
```

And then, the example service return this error:

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: null</TryitProxyError>
```

Addition, in the service dashboard (echo) I get this url to the endpoints:

```
https://null:8245/services/echo
http://null:8282/services/echo
```

I do not know if both problems have relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question again

The problem was WSO2 ESB couldn't resolve hostname because hostname file (ubuntu) had a name which wasn't in hosts file (ubuntu).